# $\sum a_n $ is convergent and $|x|<1$ then, is $\sum a_n x^n$ absolutely convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

It is clear when, $a_n>0$

$|x^n| <1$ and $|a_n x^n| < |a_n| = a_n$

Since $\sum a_n$ is convergent by comparison test $\sum |a_n x^n|$ is convergent

But will it converge absolutely even if $\sum a_n$ is not a series of postive term?

Comment: Eventually, $|a_n|<1/2$. (Or use that $|a_n|$ is bounded.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\sum a_n$ converges, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$, hence there is a positive integer $N$ such that $|a_n| \le 1$, for all $n \ge N$.

Then for $n \ge N$, we get $|a_nx^n| = |a_n||x|^n \le |x|^n$.

Hence by the comparison test, since $\sum_{n=N}^\infty |x|^n$ converges, we get that $\sum_{n=N}^\infty |a_nx^n|$ converges.

It follows that $\sum a_nx^n$ converges absolutely.

Comment: Since $a_n\to 0$ there exists $M>0$ such that $|a_n|\le M$ for $all$ $n.$  So $|a_nx^n|\le M|x|^n$ for all $n.$

Comment: Yes, I agree, that's a little simpler.